# Is it possible to create Graphql Generic Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I need pagination type for GraphQL in asp.net core.

I am trying code in below for the type:

```
using GraphQL.Types;
using WebApi.Data.Entities.Models;
using WebApi.Dtos;
using WebApi.Helpers;
using WebApi.Services;

namespace WebApi.Data.Entities.Graphql.GraphQueryTypes
{
    public class PagedResultType<T>: ObjectGraphType<T> where T : class
    {
        public PagedResultType()
        {
            Name = "PagedResultType";
            Field<IntGraphType>("CurrentPage");
            Field<IntGraphType>("PageCount");
            Field<IntGraphType>("PageSize");
            Field<IntGraphType>("RowCount");
            Field<IntGraphType>("FirstRowOnPage");
            Field<IntGraphType>("LastRowOnPage");
            Field<ListGraphType<T>>("Results");
        }
    }
}
```

Also I am trying to create `Field` on `RootQuery`:

```
    Field<PagedResultType<ComplaintSourceDTO>>(
        "complaintSourceTypes",
        arguments: new QueryArguments(
            new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "page", Description = "Sayfalama için sayfa " },
            new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "pageSize", Description = "Sayfalama için gerekli sayfa sayısı" }
        ),
        resolve: context => complaintSourceService.GetDataWithPaged(context.GetArgument<int>("page"), context.GetArgument<int>("pageSize"))
    );
```

But it says as error:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method 'ListGraphType'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'T' to 'GraphQL.Types.IGraphType'.

So is it possible to create generic graph object type?

How can I gain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue as well. I tried looking at the answer from Nkosi and must be misunderstanding it because I couldn't get it to work as described above. Here is how I solved it.

```
public class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet<T>
{
  public T[] Results { get; set; }
  public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
}

public class BookType : ObjectGraphType<Book>
{
  public BookType()
  {
    Field(b => b.Id);
    Field(b => b.Title);
  }
}

public class ResultSetType<T, TType> : ObjectGraphType<ResultSet<T>>
  where TType : IGraphType
{
  public ResultSetType()
  {
    Name = $"{typeof(TType).Name}ResultSet";
    Field<ListGraphType<TType>>("results");
    Field<IntGraphType>("totalResultsCount");
  }
}
```

This can now be used as a field in a query as follows:

```
Field<ResultSetType<Book, BookType>>(
                "books",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "pageIndex" }, new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "pageSize" }),
                resolve: ctx => booksRepository.ReadBooks(ctx.GetArgument<int>("pageIndex"), ctx.GetArgument<int>("pageSize"))
            );
```

My query allows for paging where a user(or UI) could specify how many results they want to get at once as well as which page they want to view, so it is passing in two arguments, but the part that would be of interest to you would be `Field<ResultSetType<Book, BookType>>("books");`

Answer (score 0):

[`ListGraphType<T>`](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL/Types/ListGraphType.cs) is defined as

```
public class ListGraphType<T> : ListGraphType
    where T : IGraphType
{
    public ListGraphType()
        : base(typeof(T))
    {
    }
}
```

That message implies that you are missing the [IGraphType](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL/Types/IGraphType.cs) constraint that the type argument should be derived from if you want to use it with the `ListGraphType<>`

```
public class PagedResultType<T>: ObjectGraphType<T> where T : class, IGraphType {

    //...
}
```

Adding the constraint now means that any type argument used with the page result has to be derived from `IGraphType`

For example

```
public class ComplaintSourceDTO: ObjectGraphType<ComplaintSourceDTO> { 
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Ok but at this time It has an error on creating field.The type 'WebApi.Dtos.ComplaintSourceDTO' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PagedResultType<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebApi.Dtos.ComplaintSourceDTO' to 'GraphQL.Types.IGraphType'

Comment: That would be because the constraint was added and  `ComplaintSourceDTO` does not drive from `IGraphType`

Comment: Ok. Can you illustrate please a solution with creating a field.

Comment: Just update `ComplaintSourceDTO` definition to inherit from `ComplaintSourceDTO`. ie `public class ComplaintSourceDTO: ObjectGraphType<ComplaintSourceDTO> { ... }`

Comment: So you mean like this:     `public class ComplaintSourceDTO:IGraphType
    {...}` ?